# How to add a condition based on a line-item's product type in a rules tax component?

Tags: commerce, rules

In Drupal Commerce, when you create a tax rate of a particular type, let's say a "VAT low" of type VAT, a rule "Calculate taxes: VAT" is created, as well as a rule component "Calculate VAT Low".

Now I want to make the "Calculate VAT Low" component conditional on the product type of the product referenced in the line item. The examples for conditions in the tax component that I found, however, use data selectors of the order like address, not a line item.
Other examples of using conditions based on the product type referenced by the line item are configured at the level of the rule, not the component (e.g. [here](https://drupal.org/node/1251444#comment-4874296)). The `commerce-line-item:commerce-product:type` does not seem to be available when adding conditions to a component.

Is it possible to make tax components conditional on the product type of the line item? Or should I create a separate rule for each tax rate component rather than use the default "Calculate taxes: VAT"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to use product type as a condition - it actually does work the same for rules and rules components.

When I tested this, I was adding the condition "Entity has field": `field_product`, but in order for the `commerce-line-item:commerce-product:type` data selector to appear under the Data comparison condition, you have to use the field `commerce_product`, which is the product reference field used on the line-item entity.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get the line-item:commerce-product:type from within an action loop. Did you find any useful documentation for accessing line item product types?